# Inserting record into MongoDB with MERN Stack

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to learn the MERN stack by watching this [tuturial](https://youtu.be/mrHNSanmqQ4?t=3218). However, I'm getting the following error message when trying to post to my test MongoDB.

```
{
  name: 'john',
  user_id: '1234',
  date: 2022-06-24T19:27:18.408Z,
  text: 'Great food!',
  restaurant_id: new ObjectId("5eb3d669b31de5d588f45e8f")
}
Unable to post review: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'insertOne')
```

All of the tutorial's code is located [here](https://github.com/beaucarnes/mern-exercise-tracker-mongodb/tree/master/backend).
This is the code that inserts the data into the DB:

```
static async addReview(restaurantId, user, review, date) {
    try {
      const reviewDoc = { name: user.name,
          user_id: user._id,
          date: date,
          text: review,
          restaurant_id: ObjectId(restaurantId), }
      console.log(reviewDoc)
        // insertOne is a mongoDB command
      return await reviews.insertOne(reviewDoc)
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(`Unable to post review: ${e}`)
      return { error: e }
    }
  }
```

I'm console logging the "reviewDoc" variable and I see there are no undefined values being passed. I tried using Insomnia and PostMan Apps to make the POST request but got the same error in the console and the DB is not updating. I'm new to MongoDB and still learning full-stack web development. Not sure where else to look to troubleshoot this. Any guidance or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out. I did not have ReviewsDAO imported in my index.js file. Right around [this point](https://youtu.be/mrHNSanmqQ4?t=2021) in the tutorial it imports the RestaurantsDAO but never imports the ReviewsDAO. After doing a stare and compare of my code with the instructors code I was able to figure out what was wrong.